# wifi connection error Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, 13.04, usb

I am new to Ubuntu (been using windows for many years and finally have tried to make the switch.

I am using a Cisco AE1000 USB WiFi adapter to connect to internet. Once I boot up, I usually can go for around an hour and then it all cuts out. If I remove the usb adapter and plug it back in I seem to get a few more minutes. I have been using the setup on windows 7 and it works fine there (if I boot into windows it works still).

I have been Googling for a solution and have come across many things but most people have no connection at all so I am unsure if it is the same issue.

The driver I am using is the default one Ubuntu installed: rt2800usb

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 13b1:002f Linksys AE1000 v1 802.11n [Ralink RT3572]
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c069 Logitech, Inc. M500 Laser Mouse
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 04f3:0103 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu either has picked the wrong driver (I read years ago that certain Ralink chips are prone to that) or the dongle is just incompatible and you should get another one from this list: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Devices

Note that makers switch chips from different vendors between versions.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it does seem weird that it does work for around a half an hour and continues to work if I take it out and plug it back in (for a while).